# Pandas installation error

Tags: python, macbook, pandas

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on MacBook m1 (parallels) and I have a problem when try to install pandas on python3.6 (I have to use this versions because of work). It returns an error gcc, there is the link to my GitHub repository because the error exceeds 400k characters.
I have already installed python3.6-dev, gcc, g+, etc. What is the problem? I thought this happens because of m1, but it happens also in ubuntu 22.04 [on another pc](https://github.com/vinzinz1396/errore).
Thank you for help.

Comment: In 20.04 LTS, the python included in the base system is Python 3.8 Changing the default python kills a system. Ubuntu uses and relies on the version of python that it shipped with. Do a Google search and you will see for each version of Ubuntu what the version of python it uses is. 2 things you need to do 1. re install the OS 2. Look up how to have more then one version of python on your OS.

Comment: Thank you @david, but there are a lot of problems with python libraries compilation.